# How to add a text on top of DataTables select input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using `DataTables select input` and I am capturing only the first three columns. Right now, I would like to add a text on the top of the select inputs. Is there a way to add a text on DataTables. For example `select product` on `DataTables select inputs`

I am using DataTables. Here is my `select inputs` my looks like now:

[image]

Here is a visual look of how I would like it to be -- just adding a text like this that says select something.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
 <script> 

      $(document).ready(function() {
$(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");

       $('table').DataTable( {

            fixedHeader: true,

            "ordering": false,

            columnDefs: [{ 
                        targets: 7,
                        createdCell: function(td, cellData) {
                            $(td).hover(function(){
                                if (cellData === ''){
                                    $(this).css('cursor','pointer').attr('title', 'Some text');

                                }
                            })

                            }
                        }],

            language: {
                processing:     "Bitte warten ..",
                search:         "Suchen",
                lengthMenu:    "_MENU_ Einträge anzeigen",              
                info:           "_START_ bis _END_ von _TOTAL_ Einträgen",
                infoEmpty:      "Keine Daten vorhanden",
                infoFiltered:   "(gefiltert von _MAX_ Einträgen)",
                infoPostFix:    "",
                loadingRecords: "Wird geladen ..",
                zeroRecords:    "Keine Einträge vorhanden",
                paginate: {
                    first:      "Erste",
                    previous:   "Zurück",
                    next:       "Nächste",
                    last:       "Letzte"}
                },

               initComplete: function () {

                   this.api().columns().every( function () {

                       var column = this;

                       if (column.index() <3 ) {
                       var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                           .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                           .on( 'change', function () {
                               var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                   $(this).val()
                               );

                               column
                                   .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                   .draw();
                           } );

                       column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                           select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                       } );
                   } 
                });


               }

           } );

   } );



        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the initComplete function change this

```
var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
```

to

```
var select = $('<select><option value="">Select a Platform</option></select>')
```

It works, if you need different placeholder for every select change it as per the need.

Something like this: https://codepen.io/piyush_05/pen/JjGbwZY

Comment: Thanks for this but if you look at the line above this, you will see ```if (column.index() <3 ) { ``` indicating to capture input views for the first 3 columns. Is there a way I can make it use the header instead? Or what do you think. Or is there a way to add a placeholder for each considering there is an if loop on top of it already?

Comment: It works but how do I change this under the loop for all three?

Comment: You can get the index of every column and change the placeholder on the basis of column index..

Comment: What do you mean by "Is there a way I can make it use the header instead"?

Comment: The index of the columns is from 0 to 3 if (column.index() <3 ) {  the table has an header th

Comment: I mean something like this `Select $("table th")`

Comment: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1488/datatable-select-issue please Join here

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Maybe an update here would be helpful for others :)